# I want to do and update with a case statement and End AS but getting error incorrect syntax near 'AS'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE DateRange
([Date] DATETIME, IsFutureOrPast BIT)

DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME
SET @DATE ='2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
WHILE @DATE <='2014-12-31 00:00:00.000'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO DateRange ([DATE])
        VALUES (@DATE)
        SET @Date = @Date + 1
    END

--Case Statement to check values and enter flag
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
UPDATE 
    DateRange
SET  [DATE] =
     CASE
        WHEN @CurrentDate <= [DATE] THEN 0
        ELSE 1
END AS IsPastOrFuture
FROM DateRange
WHERE [Date] IN ( 0, 1)
```

Comment: Column aliasing doesn't work on update assignments

Comment: Which begs the question, why are you trying to put an alias on a column?

Comment: And why are you trying to assign a `1` or `0` to a column named [Date]? Are you trying to add a new column to the table?

Comment: Also: it's really poor design to use **reserved keywords** like `DATE` as columns in your database tables. Use a **more descriptive**, more meaningful name for your column! Is it a `CreatedDate`? A `LastModifiedDate` ?? Make the name expressive so it's clear what it is!

Comment: Yes sorry I'm trying to add the IsPastOrFuture column to another table, can i not do this using an update statement?

Comment: @user3760364: Do you really need to add that column permanently? You could just return the result of your CASE expression in a query when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The `AS IsPastOrFuture` has no meaning to this query. Just remove it.

However, at this point you're trying to assign a `1` or `0` to a column named `[Date]`, which doesn't make much sense. Are you trying to add a new column to the table? If so, you need to first run an `ALTER` statement on the table to add the column.

Comment: Yes sorry im trying to add  the IsPastOrFuture column to another table, can i not do this using an update statement?